Large gap around foundation where concrete meets - How can I fix this properly?
I was about to re-caulk between my foundation and concrete slab (see my other post).
Now I'm seeing quite large and deep gaps between in some spots. How can I properly fix that? Or is it okay to just slab a bunch of caulk around it?



You would want to put foam backer rod into the gap. This will fill most of the gap and prevent the caulk from simply dripping through into whatever void is underneath, and keeps you from going through a dozen tubes of caulk trying to fill it. Where there's an entirely different issue that needs to be addressed first, I don't know.

Caulk doesn't fix problems. It just covers them up and makes them look prettier. You are going to have to fix this properly at some point. I like the answer from mdfst13 below. In the meantime, you could try some expanding foam deep in the cracks you got there (especially that huge hole) and then trim it off and caulk it at the surface. At least it will help keep water out until you can repair it properly.

When you have concrete inside the house and outside, you don't want them to be adjacent.  You want the concrete outside the house to be separated from that inside the house by an expansion joint.
The basic problem is that the concrete inside the house will expand at one speed, as it is being heated by the house.  This is true even if the area is basically unconditioned, like an unfinished basement.  It's still a different temperature than outside, warmer in winter or cooler in summer.  Meanwhile, the concrete outside the house will expand at a different speed.
If the inside is hotter, it will be more expanded and try to push against the cold outside concrete, cracking it.  If the inside is cooler, it will pull away from the warm outside concrete, leaving a gap (which may be the problem that you are seeing).
Foam backer rod can help with this, but what you really want to do it right is to dig out the bad concrete at the seam and put in a proper expansion joint.  You do not want exterior concrete directly against the slab nor the walls.  You want that separation there both to allow relative movement and to keep the temperature from transferring.  You want cracking in the walls and slab even less than cracking outside.
A quick Google suggests that "rubber concrete expansion joints" gets the right kind of material for the expansion joint itself.  There may be other (potentially better) alternatives but that looks like the right kind of material.  You would also of course need new concrete to replace what's damaged or that you need to remove to reach the damage.
A more specific (albeit commercial) link about expansion joints in concrete in buildings.  No affiliation, found via Google.
